# AngularJS - unexpected token "catch" on cordova android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, try-catch

I built a simple web app to run in cordova wbeview, when i install it on android 4.1 it runs without problems but when i install it on Android 2.3.6 (quite old yeah)

```
Unexpected token "catch" file.js LINE 134
```

That means this catch expression cant work :

```
 $http({
            'method':'GET',
            'url': appWS + '/api/find'
          }).then(function (response) {

           //
          }).catch(function (err) {

           //
          });
```

I cant understand why catch is not supported maybe too old android ok, but how can i fix this ?

Thank you, any help appreciated

Comment: `catch` is a reserved word (and always has been) in JavaScript and can't be used as a property name that way. (Of course, we're talking about Angular, so that may or may not be relevant.)

Comment: @Pointy thanks man for the ping, but what you suggest to do so? Cause obviously it works well on browser and on all the recent versions of android ... :)

Comment: From the Angular documentation it looks like that's supposed to be `.error(...)` and not `.catch(...)`

Comment: I'll give it a try, the problem is everyone agrees in using then().catch() instead of success().error() ... i dunno what to do actually

Comment: @Pointy and it fixed all :) now i am wondering if i must or not support old browsers since i like catch() ;P

Comment: It may be that (some) browsers were lax about enforcing that aspect of the syntax, and that newer versions fix the behavior.

Comment: Found that older versions of Android were more strict about this; newer versions were lax.  Thanks @Pointy for highlighting the spec :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite @Pointy's point, `.catch()` is the usual way of doing things with angualr promises (and the `q` library in general). I imagine that this is actually a bug in the version of android that you are testing on (as evidenced by the fact it works in a newer version).

You could try using the (equivalent) square bracket notation to call the function, like this:

```
$http(options)
  .then( function () { /* do stuff */ } )
  ['catch']( function () { /* handle errors */ } );
```

or the inside functions sintax

```
$http(options)
      .then( function () { /* do stuff */ }, function () { /* handle errors */ } );
```

Which may solve the problem.

Comment: Well, [the spec clearly says](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1) that reserved words can't be used as Identifiers.

Comment: You're right, sorry - I re-worded to sound less aggressive!

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch#Browser_compatibility talks about catch.

The key to understand is that older browsers were rather strict/conservative about "reserved keywords", they weren't sure how they'd be used in the "future". Nor how Java would interact with JavaScript.

Eventually, browser JavaScript engines and Browsers became sufficiently confident about how things would mix (roughly Java doesn't appear in source form in web pages, and these days it rarely appears in binary .class form), that it was ok to relax the constraint of "reserved words can't be used in any context" to allow them to be used in places where the parsing could be safely understood.

the "NAME" part of function NAME () {} is one of those contexts where the parsing is sufficiently safe and unambiguous.

Another is Object.PROPERTY.

Since those are all you need in order to do: Promise.catch(stuff), JavaScript allows it in modern browsers.

Android 2 devices don't have modern browsers/modern JavaScript engines, and as such, you get errors when you try to use this feature w/ the more aggressive syntax.

@Ed-Hinchliffe is correct, and his workaround is how you'd use it w/ older JS Engines.